# PHP. File size over 2 Gb and Maximum execution time

Tags: php, filesize

I use this function http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#115792 to get file/folder size over 2 GB on 32bit/64bit platforms.

```
function my_filesize($fp) {...}

$dir = opendir( 'my_path' );
print my_filesize($dir);
```

function my_filesize($fp) - see link above.

But I get **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\... on line ***

This is line:

```
if (0 === fseek($fp, - $step, SEEK_CUR)) {
```

I try use **set_time_limit(0)**.
Of course it doesn't work.

If I use http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#113457 I get the same.

What do I do?

**EDIT 2:**
It's seem I need use not opendir. I must use **fopen** and path must contain file, not directory.

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999678/php-timeout-set-time-limit0-dont-work).  There are multiple reasons you could not be allowed to remove the time limit.  There are also multiple ways to _attempt_ working around it.

Comment: It's seem I need use not opendir. I must use **fopen** and path must contain file, not directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`set_time_limit` — Limits the maximum execution time

Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the `max_execution_time` value defined in the `php.ini.`

When called, `set_time_limit()` restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as `set_time_limit(20)` is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.