# Insert large Excel file into database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, bulk-load, spout

I'm using [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) for reading an Excel file of over 500.000 records (with 7 columns each, not too much info).

The problem is my script is getting timmed out.
I've tried uploading this limits and it gets better, but so far I couldn't make a complete insert, just partial ones arround 50.000 rows.

This is not an option for me.
Is there any way to split this Excel file but on the code?
What I see is that manipulating the file even if it's not inserting into database is already slow and times out.

So... any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: you can read the file in chunks. Use ranges to read some rows, insert them and then run again with the next chunk

Comment: Hi @LelioFaieta I've tried but don't seem to find out HOW to do it with Spout. I used PHPExcel before which had this option but read It's really slow processing large files. And this one is really large and will continue to grow.

Comment: I don't know spout and you didn't share any code too. Using Phpexcel it is easy to do

Comment: Is it failing in the Upload or while processing the 50,000 rows onto the database

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, the file uploads fine, but when it starts the foreach of the rows, and inserts them, it takes too long.

Comment: How long is too long? How long does it currently take.

Comment: Check out [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11999755/2310830)

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling [`set_time_limit()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) repeatedly, for example after every row you insert. It resets the time limit each time you call it.  If your server administrator has set up a global time limit this won't allow you to exceed that, however.

But inserting half a million rows one by one into an InnoDB table in MySQL is inherently slow because it needs to do an autocommit after every row.

If you do the insert in batches you'll gain a lot of speed.  For example, your are probably doing something like this now:

```
  INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 'baker', 'charlie');
  INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (2, 'delta', 'echo');
  INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (3, 'foxtrot', 'golf');
  INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (4, 'hotel', 'india');
  INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (5, 'lima', 'mike');
```

Instead do this:

```
  INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES 
     (1, 'baker', 'charlie'),
     (2, 'delta', 'echo'),
     (3, 'foxtrot', 'golf'),
     (4, 'hotel', 'india'),
     (5, 'lima', 'mike');
```

That way you'll incur the commit overhead on MySQL for every five rows rather than for every one. Notice that you can put many rows into a single INSERT, not just five. MySQL's only limit on query length can be found with [`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335011/what-is-maximum-query-size-for-mysql).

Of course this a little more complex to program, but it's *much* faster.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file with 3,500,000 cells is not going to be fast, no matter what. It will take at least a minute, if run on powerful hardware and if the Excel file uses inline strings.

So here are the options you have:

1. If you control the creation of the Excel file you're reading, make sure it uses inline strings (that's the default behavior if you use Spout). This will speed up the reading *dramatically*. The slowness you mentioned even if you only read the first 2 lines is due to this. When not using inline strings, Spout needs to pre-process the file containing the cell values first, as they are referenced in another place. With inline strings, Spout can skip this expensive step and does a real streaming.
2. Increase the time limit setting to leave more time to your script to finish its processing ([set_time_limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php))
3. Batch your DB inserts: instead of inserting rows one by one, you should insert them 1000 by 1000 (or more). Each connection to the DB takes some time so limiting them is a good idea.

Splitting the file may work but needs to be done ahead of time (not in the same script, otherwise it will just add time to the total processing time...).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

The best way is peform this job in background by these step:

1. Upload the Excel file to server. Update the Import Job table with
   status: 0: Waiting
2. Setup and running a crob job to check this table and perform the import job if there is a field with status 0. Update the status
   to 1: Processing. Perform the import job service (batch import will
   be good solution).
   3. Update the status to 2. Completed if the import is finished successfully.
3. if error...